# If there is a simple plane graph G, can it have half the number of vertices as its dual graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I think it is not possible, but have no idea how to prove it.
All I know is that $v^*=f$, $e^*=e$, and $v+f=e+k+1$, where $k$ is the number of components of G.
Note that $f=v^*$, thus $f=2v$ and $3v=e+k+1$ if there exists such G.

Comment: Do you allow vertices of degree $1$ or $2$, which would lead to loops and multi-edges in the dual graph?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen As long as G is simple, they should be allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By counting face-edge incidences in two ways,
$$\tag1 3f\le 2e$$
because each face is at least a triangle.
With $f=2v$, we have
$$ 2e<2e+2k+2=2f+2v=3f,$$
contradiction.

---

However, there are two exceptions to $(1)$, namely when a face has only two sides, formed by the same edge counted twice: The graph with two vertices and an edge  between them. Of course, this gives us $v=2$ and $f=1\ne 2v$. Another exception is a face without edges, namely when we have one vertex and no edge. Again, $f=1\ne 2v$.

Comment: This is very clear and comprehensive, thank you for the answer!